# Unfilter one field and filter by another not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to use the All() function to unfilter a field called CycleName and then using the FILTER() function to filter using my Moment field. For some reason however combining the two functions is returning an error in PowerBI.

This is my DAX function:

```
CurrentForecastVar = CALCULATE(SUM([Amount]), FILTER(ALL(PowerBIHeadcount[CycleName]), [Moment] = "Current Forecast"))
```

And the error is: "Column 'Moment' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression."

What I find strange is that if I try filtering only PowerBI detects my Moment column correctly:

```
CurrentForecastVar = CALCULATE(SUM([Amount]), FILTER(PowerBIHeadcount, [Moment] = "Current Forecast"))
```

Why can't I unfilter CycleName and then filter by Moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cannot use the [Moment] column is because the first argument of the FILTER is a table or a function that returns a table. With

```
ALL(PowerBIHeadcount[CycleName])
```

you return a one column table that only contains CycleName and since you did not specify a table reference in your filtering conditions the functions tries to use the column from the provided table. And there is no [Moment] column init. Try specifing explicitly

```
PowerBIHeadCount[Moment] = "Current forecast"
```

That is a best practise to always specify full qualifying names.
So the final would be:

```
CurrentForecastVar = CALCULATE(SUM([Amount]), FILTER(ALL(PowerBIHeadcount[CycleName]), PowerBIHeadcount[Moment] = "Current Forecast"))
```

Another option would be that you remove the filters from the CycleName column as another argument in your CALCULATE function and leave the FILTER. E.g.:

```
CurrentForecastVar = 
CALCULATE(
SUM([Amount]),
ALL(PowerBIHeadcount[CycleName]), 
FILTER(PowerBIHeadcount, [Moment] = "Current Forecast")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ALL(PowerBIHeadcount)`.

```
CurrentForecastVar =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Amount] ), FILTER ( ALL ( 'PowerBIHeadcount' ), [Moment] = "Current Forecast" ) )
```

Using the `ALL` function on the whole table would disable any explit filter applied to any column in the table, if you are ok with that you can use this solution, otherwise you might want to use `ALLEXCEPT()`.

Let me know if this helps.